# Casting object to Base type creates duplicate variable values

Tags: c++, oop, object, casting, derived-class

How do i prevent the baseClassVariable from having different values? Casting an object to the baseclass gives me a different value.

```
class BaseClass
{
    int baseClassVariable;
    BaseClass()
    {
        baseClassVariable = randint();
    }
}

class Derived : public BaseClass
{
}

main()
{
    Derived* D = new Derived();
    BaseClass* bc = (BaseClass*)D;

    //D->baseClassVariable is not the same as bc->baseClassVariable
    print(D->baseClassVariable); 
    print(bc->baseClassVariable);
}
```

`

Comment: I don't see any such behaviour. Here check this http://ideone.com/hBIP3X

Comment: That's weird, I'm not able to replicate this issue on a separate build. I'm wondering if i'm facing memory corruption somewhere in my code. Hitting a rebuild all to see if it fixes it...

Comment: I'm not sure what your code looks like. The snippet you have provided is non-functional.